# How to generate a sub system diagram from visual studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to generate a sub system diagram of an application from its visual studio solution?

I am not looking to generate a class diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010, at least in the 2010 Ultimate edition, has an "Architecture" menu item with a "Build Dependency Graph" option.  One of the options is to build the graph "by Assembly."  It sounds like that is what you are after.